# Why Does CalendarAgent Access Strange Domains?

Tags: macos, calendar, ical, google-calendar

Okay so I have OS X's Calendar app setup using a Google calendar, and I have Little Snitch installed so I am warned when an application tries to make unrecognised outgoing requests.

What I'm seeing is that the CalendarAgent process occasionally tries to access Google domains that don't appear relevant, such as translate.google.com, feedburner.google.com or play.google.com, none of which seem necessary when I've already allow calendar.google.com.

Does anyone know why these domains are being accessed, and whether I should let allow them or just block/ignore them? When I temporarily block them it doesn't seem to affect anything, but it just seems weird for requests to go to these domains.

Answer (score 1):

I would say because those links are on calendar.google.com and Calendar app is following the links for some reason. When I go to calendar.google.com in a browser it has links for play and feed burner and translate.

Comment: Perhaps, but are those links included in data fetched by CalDAV, which I believe is what Calendar is using to get data? So far there's no obvious pattern to when the requests come up though; all the calendars are my own, and pretty much just so I can sync to an Android phone, nothing weird in the Calendar events.